# JQuery read from Json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

This is my code, here I am passing input username and password values. I have written function that input will be checked with json file. If the given input exists "login correct" alert will be displayed else "login incorrect" will be displayed.

but here for me always "login incorrect" is displayed. I do know what wrong in this function. I have tried by using array variable in the function to hold the json file data. then it work correctly. I am having trouble in checking with json file.

help me solve this problem. My input should be checked with json file it exists or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var a="user2";
    var b="password2";
    var checkval = false;

    $.getJSON('login.json', function(data) 
    {
        $.each(data,function(i,obj)
        {
            if(obj.username == a && obj.password == b)
            {
                checkval = true; 
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
    if(checkval == true)
        {
            alert("login correct");
        }
    else
        {
            alert("!!!!!-----Incorrect login Details-----!!!!!");
        }

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my login.json file

```
[
    {
            "username": "user1",
            "password": "password1"
    },
    {
        "username":"user2",
        "password" : "password2"
    }
]
```

Comment: Checking passwords in Javascript like this is a __REALLY__ bad idea. Anyone with modest Javascript skills will be able to hack into your system. You should be doing login on the server side, not in Javascript.

Comment: Not related to the answer. Why `if(checkval == true)` just use `if(checkval)`

Comment: put alert(obj.username); and check whether you have got values or not

Comment: @MattB. i am a newbie to JQuery. just learning its techniques. sure i will remember your suggestion. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax is async before the passwords and usernames are matched your code

```
 if(checkval == true)
        {
            alert("login correct");
        }
    else
        {
            alert("!!!!!-----Incorrect login Details-----!!!!!");
        }
```

is executed,try

```
$.getJSON('login.json', function(data) 
    {
        $.each(data,function(i,obj)
        {
            if(obj.username == a && obj.password == b)
            {
                checkval = true; 
                return false;
            }
        });
         if(checkval == true)
        {
            alert("login correct");
        }
    else
        {
            alert("!!!!!-----Incorrect login Details-----!!!!!");
        }

    });
```

here is a small proof of concept that when ajax is not used it works http://jsfiddle.net/aKVC2/

and here is the working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aKVC2/2/)

P.S.

as suggested by some answers setting `async:false` is one option(never avail it!!!), but since jQuery version 1.8 [**its DEPRECATED**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448011/jquery-ajax-async-deprecated-what-now)

Answer (score 1):

$.getJSON is async.. meaning it makes the call while the rest of your code runs. It is getting to if(checkval == true) before the call is made and before it can check against the values returned.

If you want to "fix" this, see this question.

[Is it possible to set async:false to $.getJSON call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765411/is-it-possible-to-set-asyncfalse-to-getjson-call)

Comment: But he has written the validation of username and password in the callback method. Which will execute after the file is loaded. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @asifsid88 the validation is inside the callback but the check he is implementing on a variable that is updated inside the callback function is outside it...

Comment: But the callback method doesn't get called until the request has been sent and a response is received. In the meantime, since it is async, the code moves on to the if statement before the callback has a chance to be called.

Answer (score 1):

Put the second if inside:

```
$.getJSON('login.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data,function(i,obj){
        if(obj.username == a && obj.password == b){
            checkval = true; 
            return false;
        }
    });
    if(checkval == true){
        alert("login correct");
    }else{
        alert("!!!!!-----Incorrect login Details-----!!!!!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ajax is asynchronous ,Your function making call before it can check against the returned value

add below line just above the $.getJson

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

Comment: its deprecated since jquery 1.8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448011/jquery-ajax-async-deprecated-what-now