# Why can i not see the json response when it returns 200 ok

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, getjson

I am making a json request that is valid however i am unable to see the response in the log when using:

```
console.log(data);
```

the first request works however the second does not.

Thanks

Comment: It is about this part. `Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` You probably use Google Chrome.

Comment: what does this mean i think the json response is gziped?

Comment: That You are on another domain than you request the data. You need to work with `.ajax()`. Like they tell here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765411/is-it-possible-to-set-asyncfalse-to-getjson-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://maps.googleapis.com supports [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), but https://api.forecast.io does not. For forecast.io, you should use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), easiest way to do that in jQuery is adding `"?callback=?"` to request URL:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.forecast.io/forecast/<API KEY>/' + lat + ',' + lon + "?callback=?", function(data1) {
            console.log(data1.currently.summary);
        });
```

However, you should avoid exposing your api key as stated in [forecast.io api docs](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2#options). Creating a reverse proxy to that service might be a good idea.

Comment: i have reset the api key now so this will no longer work on the existing fiddles thanks for your help

Comment: @JamesRand it's not just about fiddles. If you use JSONP directly to forecast.io, you have to have the API key somewhere in your JS source; someone might take that API key and abuse it. If you have access to server side of you application (and if it has one), you should create a service, that would act as a proxy that adds API key to your forecast.io requests.

Comment: ah okay this is only a personal project so it should be okay i guess i only needed to reset the api key to protect the account on forcast io