# use variable under ajax call globally in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created a java script file that get the images from flickr. Now I want that data can be accessed globally.

```
$.getJSON('js/album.json', function(data) {
    var myArray = data.children;
    $.each(myArray, function(i, item) {
        $.each(item.children, function(j, childItem){
            var childName = childItem.name;
            getFlickrImage(childName, handleData, data);
        });
    });
    new_json = data;
});
```

I want the `new_json` variable access globally. I tried a lot, after so much search on google I posted here.

Comment: You can’t. Welcome to the asynchronous world.

Comment: :( is there synchronous way that can help? @David

Comment: `new_json` is available globally (because you haven't used `var`) but it isn't available globally UNTIL the response has been returned from the server.

Comment: I know it @Adam but is there any other way?

Comment: @user3115091 - see my answer below. You need to use `callback` functions (or events) when dealing with asynchronous programming. Start with `callbacks`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pretty bad answers here so far.

In the asynchronous world of AJAX, you need to do things with `callbacks`. With AJAX, you never know when (or even if) the data that you've asked for will become available. It depends on things like the clients internet connectivity, latency, your server's speed, traffic etc.

So you have to do it like this:

```
function doSomeAjaxCall(myCallback) {

  $.getJSON('js/album.json', function(data) {
      var myArray = data.children;
      $.each(myArray, function(i, item) {
          $.each(item.children, function(j, childItem){
              var childName = childItem.name;
              getFlickrImage(childName, handleData, data);
          });
      });
      new_json = data;

      myCallback.apply(window);    

  });

});

doSomeAjaxCall(function() {
  console.log(new_json); //see? it is available globally.
});
```

Comment: Curious, what's up with the downvoter? Admittedly, this isn't the only way to do this, but there's also about ten different ways, this is just an example of one way.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, remember that any "global variable" is just a member of the window's object (when working on browsers).
So you just must use:

```
//...
window.new_json = data
//...
```

In order to access "new_json" anywhere on your code.

But remember, global variables are evil :) So I would put it inside another object at least.

As a personal advice, I think you should take a look to [Jquery's Promises](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) first, because you can't ensure elsewhere on your code that new_json is properly fulfilled. Or also think other design patterns (module pattern, maybe) in order to make your app cleaner.

Answer (score -2):

You can't. You have to make call synchronously.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765411/is-it-possible-to-set-asyncfalse-to-getjson-call/) for more information.

Comment: This answer is wrong.