# Datatable - Show Database field names in header in table html

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a database with field name

Name,
Class,
April,
May,
March,
June,
July

I would like to show the field name of the database in the datatable view dynamically instead of entering it manually, like this:

```
<tr>
    <th class="cust_th_01">#</th>
    <th class="cust_th_02">Class</th>
    <th class="cust_th_03">April</th>
    <th class="cust_th_04">May</th>
    <!--<th class="cust_th_07">June</th>
    <th class="cust_th_08">July</th>-->
</tr>
```

Is it possible, if so how?

Comment: how you get your database?  and display data?

Comment: You can do an extra Ajax request to fetch the headers. But I don’t know what it should be good for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datatables - dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070552/datatables-dynamic-columns). Or possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046139/datatables-dynamic-columns-from-ajax-data-source), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140671/datatables-with-dynamic-columns) or other similar questions. Those should give you some approaches. Otherwise, you may need to clarify your question.