# Can't get the right return value from my API call

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am using http://ip-api.com/json API and I am trying to get an object that would hold the city and and the country of a person.
This is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var locationAPI = "http://ip-api.com/json";
var K, C, F;


var Person = {
    city: function() {
        $.getJSON(locationAPI, function(data) {
            return data.city;
        });
    },
    country: function() {
        $.getJSON(locationAPI, function(data) {
            return data.countryCode;
        });
    }
};

var x = Person.city;
console.log(x); });
```

This is the output:

```
function () {
        $.getJSON(locationAPI, function(data) {
            return data.city;
        });
    }
```

I want it to output a value for ex. - Person.country = USA
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: those are asynchronous calls. They don't return the result of a request. They issue the request and return. When response comes the callback is called with the result. Its up to you to handle the result in a callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you think .getJSON is a simple function but its not, its a promise function, you have 2 ways to get the data, or in a callback function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var locationAPI = "http://ip-api.com/json";
var K, C, F;
var Person;

$.getJSON(locationAPI, function(data) {
  Person = {
    city: data.city,
    country: data.country
  };

  var x = Person.city;
  console.log(x); });

});
```

or what you can also do is in a promise like this:

```
var theCall = $.getJSON(locationAPI);

theCall.done(function(data) {...})
```

you can user .ajax() method and set async: false, this will make the code to wait for the ajax to finish and only then continue (continue only after you set your variable)

**BUT this is not the good way to do so, as it blocks the browser to wait for the call, and it might take few seconds for this to finish!!!**

```
$.ajax({
  url: myUrl,
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    //stuff
    //...
  }
});
```

you can learn more from the docs of ajax, or from this [Is it possible to set async:false to $.getJSON call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765411/is-it-possible-to-set-asyncfalse-to-getjson-call)

Comment: I had an idea in my mind that I could call the .getJSON and then keep the value of my variable person to use it outside the .getJSON or even outside the $(document).ready