# JSON request inside another JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to make a JSON request using jquery, the first JSON request return me the data I want.

After the first Success JSON request, I want to look at the results from the first JSON request and use it in my second JSON request.

The problem I am facing currently, is my second JSON request return empty object. 
Can someone help me figure out why my second JSON return nothing?

Even though when i post the second JSON url on a website url, it show me the JSON data. but in my program it is not returning anything.

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var api_wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=cat&srwhat=text&callback=?";
  var api_wiki_extract = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=info%7Cextracts&inprop=url&exsentences=1&callback=?&titles=";
  var sp;
  var linkReady = [];
  var linkR;

  $.getJSON(api_wiki, function(data) {
    sp = data.query.search;
    linkR = workWithTheData(sp);
    anotherJSON(linkR);
  }); //End of getJSON 1

  function workWithTheData(sp) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
      linkReady[i] = api_wiki_extract + sp[i].title;
    }
    return linkReady;
  }

  function anotherJSON(linkR){
    $.getJSON(linkR[0], function(data1) {
     console.log(data1); 
    });
  }

}); //End of document ready
```

Comment: the second query to wiki, give me this response: "/**/({"batchcomplete":""})" look there is no JSON code /**/. That could be?

Comment: returning empty object means server returning empty data check your url request is it valid ?

Comment: It is returning data for me: https://jsfiddle.net/r6w3pfg4/

Comment: Why don't you use $.ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things you need to understand here:

1. JSON is a data format. What you are doing is HTTP Ajax Request, provided by jQuery, which return data in JSON format.
2. Your code is totally working fine. you can see @Hanlet 's [link](http://jsfiddle.net/r6w3pfg4).

After your second Request, it will return `{batchcomplete: "", query: Object}` in Browser's Console. And once you expand the `query`, you will see everything inside.

3. The 2nd scenario that you might facing, is, may be there are some other parts affect your ajax request.

You can try to to convert back to normal `$.ajax` request and set `async: false`
[Is it possible to set async:false to $.getJSON call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765411/is-it-possible-to-set-asyncfalse-to-getjson-call)

Comment: but data1 is empty object, whereas if you copy the html ajax request to a browser you get different result.

Comment: Thanks I just needed to expand it ... didn't know that data is unexpand in codepen the place where i am programming them

Comment: @HeshamIsmailIsmail yes, because it's an array object, so normally console browser will minimize it.