# deferring return of $.getJSON with async set to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have attempted various solutions I have seen in other questions, but am not successfully logging `data.ip`.

When I log `foo` I only return `undefined`. Why is the `ip` property not being logged with `async` set to `false`?

TY

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
  async: false
});

var getIp = function() {
  var ip;
  $.getJSON('//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(data) {
    ip = data.ip;
  });
  return ip;
}

var foo = getIp();
console.log(foo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is valid JSON returned from the requested page?

Comment: @Marcin: Yes, valid JSON returned from requested page.

Comment: Never, ever, ever set `async` to `false`. It will seriously harm the performance of your web page.

Comment: **Don't use `async:false`** Use the asynchronous callback pattern properly

Comment: $.getJSON does not accept `async: false` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765411/is-it-possible-to-set-asyncfalse-to-getjson-call

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed You are aware the next answer down shows you how to use `$.getJSON` with `async:false`?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ also does not list `async: false` anywhere

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed Please stop and read the next answer down from the [link you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6676835/2315360).

Comment: @George Okay. I Stand corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not implementing AJAX correctly. I changed your function so that it will return a `Promise` (note the `return` keywords in the function). Afterwards inside `.then()` you can pass a callback function which will be executed once the `Ajax` has finished.`$.getJSON()` is an implementation of `Ajax` (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

**NOTE:**

I strongly recommend NOT to use `async: false` inside any `xhr / Ajax` due to it will slow down your website. Better use the code below:

```js
var getIp = function() {
  var ip;
  return $.getJSON('//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(data) {
    return data.ip;
  });
}

getIp().then(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: edited the answer