# jQuery $.getScript how to reference retrieved data outside of that function

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON file that looks something like this:

```
var sourceData = [
{
"id":"c1",
"title":"What color are your eyes?"
}
]
```

I want to load it via jQuery so I can retrieve the data later:

```
var myData = $.getScript('data_c1.json', function(data, textStatus){
console.log(data); 
return data
});
console.log(myData)
```

When I look in the console, 2 things are not what I expect:

1. the logs hit the console in reverse order
2. `data` returns correctly, however `myData` returns the `$.getScript` function itself, rather than the data.

For the record, I also tried

```
$.getJSON("sourceData_c1.json", function(json) {console.log(json);});
```

and that didn't work for me at all.

I'm stumped. Any help greatly appreciated!

Also, is it valid syntax to place `var sourceData =`  inside the JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$.getJSON()` then the output from your file would need to be in JSON format like so (without the variable declaration):

```
{ "status" : "success",
  "msg"    : "2 items returned.",
  "output" : [
    { "id" : "c1", "title" : "What color are your eyes?" },
    { "id" : "c2", "title" : "What color are your ears?" }
  ]
}
```

> The callback is passed the returned JavaScript file. This is generally
>   not useful as the script will already have run at this point.
>
> The script is executed in the global context, so it can refer to other
>   variables and use jQuery functions. Included scripts can have some
>   impact on the current page

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Basically when you use `$.getScript()`, once the callback function has fired that means that the code in the script you've loaded is already in the DOM and can be accessed:

```
$.getScript('data_c1.json', function(data){
    //since we are in the callback function, the `sourceData` variable should be added to the DOM and accesible
    console.log(sourceData);
});
```

Note that your script file should have a `.js` file extension if you are returning JavaScript. If you want to return JSON instead then use `$.getJSON()` or set the `contentType` of the AJAX call to `json` so it will be properly parsed.

Also note that the `myData` variable was being set to the `jqXHR` object and not the response of the AJAX call.

Comment: the JSON output syntax helped me (thank you!), but I still couldn't get it to be available outside of the function, then I found this post which is exactly what I was looking for: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739800/variables-set-during-getjson-function-only-accessible-within-function