# How could I keep resending this ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, setinterval

I've tried to use setinterval to allow my ajax request to send every 2 seconds but it keeps crashing the page, So I think something is going wrong!

Here is my code:

```
 var fburl = "http://graph.facebook.com/http://xzenweb.co.uk?callback=?";

        //getting facebook api content
        $.getJSON(fburl, function(data){

        var name = data["shares"];
        var dataString = 'shares='+name;

        //sending share count data to server
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,

        success: function(html)
        {
        $("#content").html(html);
        }
    });
return false;   
});
```

I'm new to both ajax and javascript, would really appreciate it if you could help me out :)

Comment: well I made get.JSON request to Facebook to retrieve the information I wanted then sent it via ajax via $.ajax

Comment: Please provide the `setinterval` part. It's rather hard to crash the page. You probably have an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Konrad - I know haha I feel like such a noob.

Comment: Here was the set interval code: setInterval(function() {//getting facebook api content
        $.getJSON(fburl, function(data){

        var name = data["shares"];
        var dataString = 'shares='+name;

        //sending share count data to server
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,

        success: function(html)
        {
        $("#content").html(html);
        }
    });
return false;   
});

Comment: and at the bottom of that: }, 2000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a callback function to the $.getJson

```
function test(){
         $.getJSON(fburl, 
              function(data) {
                  //your method
              }); 
         setInterval("test()",2000);
      }
```

**UPDATED ANSWER ::**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    test();
  });


function test(){
    $.getJSON("http://graph.facebook.com/http://xzenweb.co.uk?callback=?", 
         function(data) {
         var name = data["shares"];
            var dataString = 'shares='+name;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,

                success: function(html)
                {
                $("#content").html(html);
                }
            });
            return false;  
         }); 
    setTimeout("test()",5000);
 }




</script>


<body>
<div id="content">Hello</div>
</body>
```

Comment: would I include the ajax request in function test()?

Comment: hm it doesn't seem to be working for me...now nothing is appearing

Comment: You have to include your ajax call in place of "your method" but i would suggest reading this link before that .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1739812/1085285

Comment: Hi Fidrizers I've included my ajax call in //your method but nothing is appearing :S

Comment: are u  calling  the test function somewhere??   see the edit ..(used fbUrl instead of fburl)

Comment: yey it works!! However it still seems to pretty slow, like it's going to crash!

Comment: pretty fast on mine .. seems like problem in your index.php  code. can u check in firebug net panel about the time taken for response. And Pls accept the answer . :) if its fixed

Comment: my php is just simply if(isset($_POST["shares"])) {
echo $_POST["shares"];
}

Comment: in my console it's constantly posting to index.php at around 653ms average, but my site still is slow and crashy :(

Comment: here's my code: function test(){
  $.getJSON(fburl, function(data){

        var name = data["shares"];
        var dataString = 'shares='+name;
  
        
  //sending share count data to server
  $.ajax({
  async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        
  success: function(html)
        {
        $("#content").html(html);
        }
    });
});
setInterval("test()",2000);
} 
test();

Comment: probably an issue with something else. Open another question for that . and pls accept the answer if it worked.  and dont forget to add  async: false as option in ur ajax call.

Comment: thanks for all your help, I'll open up another question now haha!