# access data outside getJSON

Tags: asynchronous, getjson

I am so stuck with access/store data outside getJSON

```
var arr = new Array();  // an array to store result

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data.data, function(index, value){
    arr.push(value);
    }

 }
```

### need to access arr here.

I tried using $ajax, async:false(as this post indicate [Variables set during $.getJSON function only accessible within function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739800/variables-set-during-getjson-function-only-accessible-within-function)), but still no luck. I know this question has been asked many times and I did some search, but still havent make it work. Tons of thanks

Comment: do you look at this Solution on SO..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739800/variables-set-during-getjson-function-only-accessible-within-function?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
var arr = [];
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
   arr = data;
});
```

You're taking the array produced by the JSON decode, and then assigning its values in a loop. you could just assign the whole array at once, preserving the keys from the original json array as is.  Your code is preserving only values.