# AngularFire2 access data after retrieve it

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm trying to get the data from my Firebase with AngularFire2.
I want to check specific data and after I get this data from Firebase, I can check it only in the specific scope and not after the operation to Firebase. Why does it happen?

Below is my code:

```
 this.af.database.list('/users/1qfcMAQnglX9jsW5GdLpPko1HqE2', { preserveSnapshot: true})
.subscribe(snapshots=>{
    snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
      if(snapshot.key=="reg_boolean"){
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        this.bo=snapshot.val();
      }
      this.currentUser.push({key:snapshot.key,value:snapshot.val()});
      console.log(this.currentUser);
      //console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
      if(this.bo==true){console.log("happy"); }; //i can access only in this scope
    });

})
 if(this.bo==true){console.log("happy"); }; //why i can access this value??it's undefined, this happen before the subscribe with angularfire2
```

[image]

Comment: Victor's answer explains, but I'll also refer you to these reference questions: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/), [Variables set during $.getJSON function only accessible within function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1739800) and [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](http://stackoverflow.com/1/5316697).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's undefined because `this.af.database.list` it's asynchronous so the code in `subscribe` will execute when `this.af.database.list` does retrieve the data. So when the code got to the line `if(this.bo==true){console.log("happy"); };` It has nothing because subscribe did not finish at all.

The subscribe it's like the old promise but now it's working with rxjs I recommend you to learn it because angular and ionic has a lot of focus on that.

Try looking at https://www.learnrxjs.io/

Comment: Victor do you have any solution for me now or anything can solve this issue? because I'm not sure how to work with rxjs.

Comment: @AdirZoari what do you want to do with the data?

Comment: okay i explain you in general. after sign up in his first time he create account and complete to fill all the required data(department name,year), i set the reg_boolean to true means if next time he enter to app, it checks in data, if the reg_boolean is true so he doesn't need to choose department name and year again so it nav to homepage and not sign up.

Comment: Check it https://gist.github.com/vigohe/cedbf896503255d3babb7ebbe1ceb934

Comment: hey victor, i did that and i get the error when i run it TypeError: _this._myService.getRegBoolean(...).filter is not a function

Comment: @AdirZoari I did add the missing filter import.

Comment: victor, I appreciate your help. now it's compiled but although the reg_boolean is true it's not show mean and not enter to where i nav it. i even print with console.log to see the result but it's not go to it.

Comment: @AdirZoari Can you add the template part please.

Comment: sure https://gist.github.com/adirzoari/6f8818a7ef95f9276f3576cb2a60da6d

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain my self right. I use in firebase as database. each user who signup to my app has reg_boolean attribute in db, if he already finish so i want it to go directly to HomePage, if not so the regBoolean is be False and then he go to signUpPage. did you get the idea?