# Assigning variable a value in $.getJSON then accessing outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, getjson

I'm pretty new to js.

I'm using flask in python to create a website.
What I want to do is generate a chart using googlecharts and data from an sql database.
In one of my urls, I'm "jsonifying" the data and attempting to access it in js via "$.getJSON" as follows:

```
var males;
var females;

$.getJSON("/getstats", function(data){
    for (obj of data){
        males=obj.males;
        females=obj.females;
    }
});
```

But the variables' values aren't changing to equal `obj.females` and `obj.males`.

They do change to anything I assign them outside the $getJSON brackets.

I stumbled upon [Variables set during $.getJSON function only accessible within function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739800/variables-set-during-getjson-function-only-accessible-within-function) which seemed to be similar to my question; but I tried the solution within the question's "UPDATE #2" and it still didn't work.

How can I reach the values of `obj.females` and `obj.males`?

Comment: How do you know, that values are not changed? I mean there's no code using the variables ...

Comment: You're already reaching those values inside the callback. Since that's where you've had success in accessing the data, maybe that's where you should utilize the data.

Comment: The answer is in the thread you posted - not the question, but the answers. It’s not about where the code is, but **when** the code runs.

Comment: Also, it doesn't really seem to make sense to have a loop here; you will re-set `males` and `females` in each iteration. Are you sure the source data actually contains an array of objects? Maybe it is just a single object.

Comment: how does `data` look like?

Comment: @Teemu: I'm generating a chart using the value of the variables males and females. The values are not equal to obj.males/females.

Comment: I've a hunch you haven't fully understood how asynchronous requests work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323 . Notice, that the provoded code works as it is, if you'd read the values of the variables in that callback function, they would have the values (last) assigned in the `for .. in ` loop.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Oh god, you were right. It was a single object. ^^"" Thank you so much.
In such cases should I just go ahead and delete my original post?